# In EF 4.1 DbContext how to trace generated SQL

Tags: sql, logging, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, trace

I wonder how to  trace generated SQL like DataContext in LinqToSql.

I also read articles about the solution of EFProviderWrapper on Jaroslaw Kowalski's blog, but it is based on ObjectContext, does not work for DbContext.

Anyone know how to do this in DbContext?

Thank you.

Comment: This is actually very good question.

Comment: This is one of those [features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx) that Microsoft wants you to spend a lot more money to get (Visual Studio Ultimate). There are some 3rd party libraries that make it easier though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC-Mini-Profiler is a pwerful tool, not ony trace generated sql, but also profiling tool.

[Using mvc-mini-profiler database profiling with Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first/6743941#6743941)

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way with `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>` is just to use `ToString()` on the `IQueryable` you have built. For example:

```
var query = context.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts)
                   .Where(b => b.Title == "AnyTitle");

string sql = query.ToString();
```

`sql` contains the SQL command which will be issued to the DB when the query gets executed.

Comment: That only helps if you are doing a search (that returns an IQueryable).  If you are adding, modifying and deleting entities how do you view that sql?

Comment: @codemonkey: True, works only for queries. I don't think that there is any built-in way to trace *all* SQL statements with DbContext.

Comment: I came here to ask @codemonkey 's question. Everything I'm finding shows the former, no luck yet on the latter.

Comment: @Slaima: but how can i log generated Sql from SaveChanges() statement via DBContext?

Answer (score 0):

I use the SQL Server profiler tool to see exactly what SQL has been created.  There is also http://efprof.com/ but it has quite a high price.

Comment: Thank you, I  know that tool. And I'm looking for a DIY solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) method to view store commands (SQL statements for example). The [How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896348.aspx) on MSDN will show you how it can be used.

Note that in many cases, you will be able to cast an IQueryable (the return type from Linq extension methods such as [IQueryable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx)) to an ObjectQuery so that you have access to the ToTraceString method.

Comment: this is not quite convenient. I recommend this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first/6743941#6743941

Answer (score 0):

I found this EFTracingProvider extension for the ObjectContext here:

http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/

But the example is for ObjectContext not DbContext, to get it to work with DbContext 
do the following in the constructor:

```
Public Sub New()
  MyBase.New(EFTracingProviderUtils.CreateTracedEntityConnection("MyDbConnection"), True)
  Dim context As ObjectContext = CType(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
  context.EnableTracing()
End Sub
```

Oh and remember to set the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="EntityFramework.MyDbConnection" switchValue="All" />
    </sources>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

That then traces all the SQL to immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not wanting to pull in a third party library, and is simply looking for the SQL containing the parameters (and isn't upset by all the reflection), this extension method grabs the InternalQuery object and the ObjectQuery object from the DbQuery and returns the ToTraceString after realizing the Parameters back into the string.  If it fails it return the parameter-less ToString from the IQueryable:

```
    public static string ToSqlString<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable) where TEntity : class
    {
        try
        {
            var dbQuery = queryable as DbQuery<TEntity>;

            // get the IInternalQuery internal variable from the DbQuery object
            var iqProp = dbQuery.GetType().GetProperty("InternalQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

            var iq = iqProp.GetValue(dbQuery);

            // get the ObjectQuery internal variable from the IInternalQuery object
            var oqProp = iq.GetType().GetProperty("ObjectQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

            var oq = oqProp.GetValue(iq);

            var objectQuery = oq as ObjectQuery<TEntity>;

            var sqlString = objectQuery.ToTraceString();

            foreach (var objectParam in objectQuery.Parameters)
            {
                if (objectParam.ParameterType == typeof(string) || objectParam.ParameterType == typeof(DateTime) || objectParam.ParameterType == typeof(DateTime?))
                {
                    sqlString = sqlString.Replace(string.Format("@{0}", objectParam.Name), string.Format("'{0}'", objectParam.Value.ToString()));
                }
                else if (objectParam.ParameterType == typeof(bool) || objectParam.ParameterType == typeof(bool?))
                {
                    bool val;
                    if (Boolean.TryParse(objectParam.Value.ToString(), out val))
                    {
                        sqlString = sqlString.Replace(string.Format("@{0}", objectParam.Name), string.Format("{0}", val ? 1 : 0));
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    sqlString = sqlString.Replace(string.Format("@{0}", objectParam.Name), string.Format("{0}", objectParam.Value.ToString()));
                }
            }

            return sqlString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //squash it and just return ToString
            return queryable.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a problem with this solution when there are more than 10 parameters. Let's say a parameter is called p10. When you replace p1 with it's value, you end up with invalid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code and then run this query to see the last SQL executed.

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight improvement over the solution (by @kmk) that replaces parameters with values. This solution declares and assigns the parameters instead:

```
    public static string ToSqlString<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable) where TEntity : class
    {
        StringBuilder parametersBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            var dbQuery = queryable as DbQuery<TEntity>;

            // get the IInternalQuery internal variable from the DbQuery object
            var iqProp = dbQuery.GetType().GetProperty("InternalQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

            var iq = iqProp.GetValue(dbQuery, null);

            // get the ObjectQuery internal variable from the IInternalQuery object
            var oqProp = iq.GetType().GetProperty("ObjectQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

            var oq = oqProp.GetValue(iq, null);

            var objectQuery = oq as ObjectQuery<TEntity>;

            var sqlString = objectQuery.ToTraceString();

            foreach (var objectParam in objectQuery.Parameters)
            {
                SqlMetaData metadata = SqlMetaData.InferFromValue(objectParam.Value, objectParam.Name);
                string sqlType = metadata.TypeName + (metadata.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.NVarChar ? "(" + metadata.MaxLength + ")" : String.Empty);

                parametersBuilder.AppendFormat("declare @{0} {1} = '{2}'", objectParam.Name, sqlType, objectParam.Value);
                parametersBuilder.AppendLine();
            }

            parametersBuilder.AppendLine();
            return parametersBuilder.ToString() + sqlString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //squash it and just return ToString
            return queryable.ToString();
        }
    }
```