# mvc miniprofiler uses DbConnection and entity framework EntityConnection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I feel I am missing something really simple here, I am integrating MVC Miniprofiler into my project but I can't find the way to instantiate my context with the right connection, because it is not EF Code First and my model inherits from ObjectContext, here is my code

```
public static MyModel GetDataBaseModel()
{       
    DbConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Utils.GetConnectionString());

    // this returns a DBConnection
    DbConnection profiledConnection = MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(conn);  

    //my model needs an EntityConnection, so this is not possible
    return new MyModel(profiledConnection); 
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802855/miniprofiler-with-ef-model-first-edmx-model

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `MyModel` is the context created by the Entity Framework Designer, right? An EntityConnection can be created from a DbConnection in combination with a `MetadataWorkspace`. I also assume that the EF Designer has added a connectionstring-property to your app/web.config which contains something like this:

```
metadata=res://*/Content.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Content.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Content.MyModel.msl;
```

These are the 3 components that make up your MetadataWorkspace. To create your an EntityConnection from these information you must provide each file within an array:

```
string[] paths =
{
    // "res://" refers to a embedded resource within your DLL, this is automatically done if
    // you've used the EF designer.
    "res://*/Content.MyModel.csdl",
    "res://*/Content.MyModel.ssdl",
    "res://*/Content.MyModel.msl"
};

Assembly[] assembliesToConsider = new Assembly[]
{
    typeof(MyModel).Assembly
};

System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace workspace = new System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace(paths, assembliesToConsider);
EntityConnection connection = new EntityConnection(workspace, profiledConnection);
```

I haven't tested this with the MvcMiniProfiler (first installed it right now), but there might be some issues, if the profiled-connection doesn't exactly behave like the original MySqlConnection, give a try otherwise a will try to create your setup.