# Trouble getting mvc mini profiler to work with EF 4.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, mvc-mini-profiler

I've scoured through stack overflow posts but no luck thus far.  I've started a new MVC 3 project that uses Entity framework 4.2.  I used nuget to install packages MiniProfiler, MiniProfiler.MVC3, and MiniProfiler.EF (MiniProfiler.EF was also added to my domain layer). Without profiling entity framework, everything works fine.  When I profile EF by uncommenting the line `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();`, I get the error:

**A provider factory for the specified store connection of type  'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection' could not be discovered. The registered provider factories and all provider factories in the assembly where 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection' is defined were searched for a factory that would produce a matching connection.**

I tried get the latest source code as I read the update for EF 4.1 required it.  Now, when I run the project I get the error:

**Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection'.**

The documentation I've gone through is a little confusing as I can't tell what is new and what is old.  From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286481/unable-to-determine-the-provider-name-error-with-mvc-mini-profiler-1-9) it seems I need to modify anything in my web.config.  Is there another step I'm missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried trunk and the new intialization routine

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sam. I should preface with I'm new to mini-profiler so thanks for bearing with me. I got the trunk and am running the Sample.MVC project.  The sql profiling works great on the SQLite connection. When I click the EF Code First Ajax Request on the home controller, I don't see the sql query and call stack with the 'First Count' and 'Insertion' profiling steps that I did with the 'Insert Routehits' step. I know in the past the profiled connection had to be supplied with the DbContext ctor but from what I can gather this isn't needed anymore.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Manny Having a similar problem (unable to determine the provider name for connection of type ...). Did you figure this out yet?

Answer (score 1):

You should put `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();` line **before** any access to database:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
       MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();

       // Start access database from here ...
       // For example call MyDbContext.Database.Exists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this entry in your Web.config file?

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" />
      <add name="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" description="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" type="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProviderFactory, MvcMiniProfiler.EntityFramework, Version=1.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```