# Mvc MiniProfiler WrappedConnection Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, connection, wrapper, mvc-mini-profiler

How could I get the value from the WrappedCOnnection Property of a ProfiledDbCOnnection?

I know the property exists however its modifier does not allow me to get it during my development;

I need to get the underlying connection for I need to involve Entity framework in the same transaction a procedure call will be involved (because Entity framework does not allow me mapping this stored procedure on it)

I am using Oracle database, and the wrapped connection is a Devart Connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using MvcMiniProfiler 1.7. Now in MvcMiniProfiler 1.9 the property `WrappedConnection` was made public.

It is important to notice that probably if you are using Entity Framework together with MvcMiniprofiler, your app may fail compiling, just as happened to me, and the solution was found here:

[Mini profiler upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9 breaks existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257271/mini-profiler-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9-breaks-existing-code)