# In Entity Framework Code First(DbContext) how to handle Azure connection faults & retrys?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I read about the [SQL Azure and Entity Framework Connection Fault Handling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/12/11/sql-azure-and-entity-framework-connection-fault-handling.aspx) article that describes about implementing Retry Policy in `OnContextCreated` (for `ObjectContext`). How to achieve the same for Entity Framework Code First `DbContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this blog post.  It's got the answer you are looking for.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2012/04/24/entity-framework-code-first-dbcontext-and-sql-azure-connection-fault-handling.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well, and I think I have a possible solution. [This code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Reliable-Retry-Aware-BCP-a5ae8e40/sourcecode?fileId=22213&pathId=579782351) by Microsoft can be used to create a reliable connection. In your DbContext class override the constructor to use the reliable connection (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first) for an example). The only problem is Microsoft's connection is an IDbConnection and the DbContext is using DbConnection.