# ASP MVC many-to-many relationship - retrieve data from associated table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I am trying to create a database with a many-to-many relationship using EF code first.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Presentations { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        Presentations = new HashSet<Item>();
    }
}

public class ItemsEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

After that I'm adding an Item to the database

```
var tag = new Tag { Text = "tag1" };
var item = new Item
{
    Description = "description1",
    Tags = new List<Tag>()
};
item.Tags.Add(tag);
using (var db = new ItemsEntities())
{
    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that I can't output items with their associated tags. The controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ItemsEntities db = new ItemsEntities();
    return View(db.Items.ToList());
}
```

and the view page has the following code:

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach (var tag in item.Tags)
        {
            @tag.Text
        }
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I expect the table to contain "description1" and "tag1" but I get only "description1". I really don't understand where the problem is. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation properties need to be marked `virtual`.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Presentations { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        Presentations = new HashSet<Item>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly where the problem was

Comment: No problem, it is a common first-timer gotcha. Note that this is also the case with non-collection navigation properties.

Comment: I disagree. It is not the `virtual` keyword that introduces the n+1 problem, and that is all I introduced. N+1 can be avoided by eager loading the related entities, yes. But that is more information than the question asked for.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work, you could mark your collection properties as `virtual` stated by @danludwig. By marking the collection properties as `virtual` EF Code First will lazy load those properties when iterating over the items in your view. You run into a SELECT N+1 problem using this approach. Let's examine your view code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
   <tr>
     <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)
     </td>
     <td>
       @foreach (var tag in item.Tags)
       {
         @tag.Text
       }
     </td>
   </tr>
}
```

In this `foreach` loop you iterate over all items in your Model that were selected using the EF data context.

```
db.Items.ToList()
```

This is your first select. But in your view above every time you access an item's `Tags` property another select is executed. The important thing is **FOR EVERY ITEM**. That means if you have 100 `Items` in `db.Items` `DbSet`, you'll execute 101 selects. This is not  acceptable for most systems.

A better approach is to pre select the tags for each item. One approach is to use   [`Include`](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/) or to select the tags related to an item into dedicated object.

```
public class ItemWithTags 
{
    public Item Item { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get;set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ItemsEntities db = new ItemsEntities();

    var itemsWithTags = db.Items.Select(item => new ItemWithTags() { Item = item, Tags = item.Tags});
    return View(itemsWithTags.ToList());
}
```

In your view you can iterate over the `itemsWithTags` collection, access items's properties and for tags you access the `Tags` property of `ItemWithTags`.

Another problem with your code is, that the **ItemsEntities** `DbContext` is opened in your code but never closed. You can use the VS MVC Templates to generate a Controller that handles `DbContext` opening and closing correctly!

You can use a tool like MVC Mini Profiler for to inspect the commands executed against the database. This [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first) shows how to set up MVC Mini Profiler with EF Code First.

Comment: -1 for introducing entity model that cannot employ lazy loading for navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll keep this in mind. Could you please explain the part about closing ItemsEntities? I thought that `using (var db = new ItemsEntities()) {}` should handle disposal after ItemsEntities is used

Comment: In your code ItemEntities is closed correctly when you add new items but not when you query these items in the `Controller.Index` method