# Log all linq queries executed on DbContext - C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a simple way to log all linq queries executed in an application?

I am currently using code first entity framework with a `DbContext` instead of the older `DataBaseContext`.I know for a fact that the `DataBaseContext` class has a `Log` property, but i do not know if there is something like the log property for the `DbContext`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: No [EF unfortunately doesn't have any build in logging](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1051017-support-for-sql-logging). You must use SQL profiler, EF related profiler or you must write EF provider wrapper which will do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174261/entity-framework-and-queries-sql-logging

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.ToString()` on [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) queries that you'll create. It will return SQL statement that will be executed on DB.
Then if you're using [`Repository`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/489326/Complex-Queries-With-Repository-Pattern-and-the-En) pattern you can implement your logging logic without using any third-party libs.